# How to run multiple Gaussian jobs one after another in Linux

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, gaussian, high-performance-computing

I want to run multiple Gaussian jobs (one after one). I have a folder which contains more than 30 molecules and I want my calculation to start with molecule 1 then when the job is finished, start the next job for molecule 2 automatically and so on ...

I know how to do it in Windows by using a batch file and executing in the utilities menu but, on Linux, I don't know how does it works.

Comment: Are you running on a cluster or on your own PC? because I think a simple bash script won't do if you are on a cluster

Comment: I'm on my PC I'm not using a cluster

Comment: As a comment: a) Get in touch with your colleagues already using Gaussian.  Because some of the computations may take some long time to complete, their infrastructure where Gaussian is set up often is a a Linux cluster. b) Join the keywords *gaussian batch job linux* in a search engine of your preference and to retrieve documentations as e.g., by Gaussian (https://gaussian.com/running/), HPC centres (https://hpc-uit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/applications/chemistry/Gaussian/job-example.html), or like Gaussian's video channel (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcqnZb8Cyw8).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets suppose that you have several Gaussian input files with extension `gjf` inside a folder.

Supposing you are in the folder where all the input files are and the command to run Gaussian is `g16`:

- Open a plain text editor and create a file with the content below (Use `nano`, `vim`, `gedit`. Don't use `LibreOffice`, `OpenOffice` or similar).
- Save the file, for example, as: `run_gaussian_jobs.sh`.
- In the command prompt, turn the file an executable: `chmod +x run_gaussian_jobs.sh`.
- Run the script as `./run_gaussian_jobs.sh`. You can also move your script to a folder that is in your path (for example `~/bin`). In that case you can use the script in any other folder where you have Gaussian input files running it as `run_gaussian_jobs.sh`.

Text to use:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.gjf; do
  extension="${file##*.}"
  filename="${file%.*}"

  g16 < $file > $filename.log
done
```

Using this approach, you can add any number of Gaussian input files to the folder without the need to known the filenames, modify the script, etc.

An aside note: running as mention before, the jobs will be running in the terminal, so, you can not close it because you will end the jobs. A better approach is to add `&` at the end of the running command: `./run_gaussian_jobs &`. Now the jobs will run in the background. You can use this if you are running the jobs in a remote computer.

Comment: Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 3):

Loops in Linux are possible, but I personally find it more convenient to make a batch-processing script. The following is an example for my [PotFit program](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/potfit), in which the command to run the program is:

```
brdpot [input_filename]
```

For example, I would create a file called `batch.x` that looks like this:

```
brdpot input1
brdpot input2
brdpot input3
brdpot input4
brdpot input5
brdpot input6
brdpot input7
brdpot input8
```

By running the command `chmod +x batch.x`, it becomes an "executable" file. You can then execute it from the directory in which it lives, by running the command `./batch.x` and this will get the computer to run the command `brdpot input1`, then when that job is complete it will get the computer to run the command `brdpot input2`, etc. **In other words, the PotFit program will be run for several input files, one-after-the-other until all jobs have been run.**

I've found this approach extremely helpful because in VIM, I can just "yank" a line in the `batch.x` file and repeat it hundreds of times, then change the number in the file name in a batch too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer . I have  a question sir do I have to mention the name "file.out'  like when I execute a basic calculus in Linux "g16 file.gjf file.out " or is it automatically and also the commend bedpost stands for what because It seems that I couldn't find it in Google thank you

Comment: @ImeneYd I'm having a hard time understanding your comment. Perhaps you can ask it in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117114/hpqc-high-performance-quantum-computing) so that we can communicate with longer comments.

Comment: I suspect "commend bedpost" is what happens when the OPs spellchecker is thrown at "command brdpot"

Comment: "Loops in Linux are possible" is a bit of an understatement :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create a script. Let's say you want to run g16 on all Gaussian inputs in the current working directory, `*.com`. The shell command

```
$ for f in *.com; do g16 $f; done
```

accomplishes what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much sir